# How to run a function when a long press has ended swift sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I'm running a very simple code and I'm trying to detect when a long press has ended and then execute a function but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. I have looked at lots of resources online but I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm very new to coding in Swift so if the answer is simple I apologize in advance. Here's all the code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let char = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "flying character")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        setScene()
    }

    @objc func press() {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 1.5)
        if UILongPressGestureRecognizer.State.changed == .ended {
            print ("the gesture has ended")
        }
    }

    func setScene() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 221/255, alpha: 1.0)
        char.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width/5, height: frame.size.width/5)
        char.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi*11/6, duration: 0.00001))
        char.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - 100, y: frame.midY + 150)
        addChild(char)
        char.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: char.size.width/2)
        char.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.charCategory
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: -1.5)
        char.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        view?.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(press)))
    }
}
```

as you can see I'm just trying to execute the print command when the long press has ended.

Comment: Use the `touchesEnded` method?

Comment: I am not following your code.... your gravity change is going to happen on all events.  Did you mean to place the gravity change into the end event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a very important thing you might notice is that **your problem is not related to SpriteKit itself**! You are using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, a class  from **UIKit**!
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer)

Also, note that you are applying the gesture to the whole view. As I assume that this is a game with a character that flies, I imagine that this behaviour is the intended one.

I imagine that the problem you are facing is that **you are not working with the UILongPressGestureRecognizer assigned to your view**! Instead, you are accessing UILongPressGestureRecognizer **class properties/methods**. For more details you can browse [this section of the Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html)

---

A quick solution to you problem is to change your press function from

```
@objc func press() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 1.5)
    if UILongPressGestureRecognizer.State.changed == .ended {
        print ("the gesture has ended")
    }
}
```

to

```
@objc func press(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 1.5)
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        print ("the gesture has ended")
    }
}
```

and your setScene function from

```
view?.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(press)))
```

to

```
view?.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(press:)))
```

[More information here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_long-press_gestures)

---

SpriteKit handles touch events in a quite raw way, but it might give you a bit more control on how you want to respond to these events. As KnightOfDragon said, it's quite like reinventing the wheel.

If you want to take a look on how SpriteKit does it, [see this example.](https://www.checksimgames.com/handling-touches-in-a-spritekit-game/) It's quite short, but I hope it helps :)

Comment: I agree with everything but "SpriteKity".  The gesture works fine with SpriteKit, and is the SpriteKit way.  you just need to handle translation in the recognizer function.  All your example does is provide how to handle touch events, not gestures, there by telling the user that they need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Fine! Totally agree. Edited answer to better reflect it :)

Comment: I actually would just eliminate the example comment all together LOL.  I would instead mention using SKScene's `convertPoint(fromView point:CGPoint)` when dealing with a gesture